# Python not equal operator

Tags: python, deprecated, not-operator

I come from a c style languages, so I am natural in using `!=` as not equal, but when I came to Python, from the documentation I read, I learned that for this purpose the `<>` operator is used.

Recently, I have seen a lot of code using `!=`, so my question is if one of them is preferred  over the other or is one of them deprecated.

Also, I would like to know if there is any difference between them.

Comment: which documentation did you read this in?

Comment: @hayden I don't really remember . I have found this on the official python documentation, I don't know if it was there, but now it is. http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: @AndyHayden: I also for some reason favored `<>` in my python because of some documentation or book I read and also don't remember which one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python 2 supports *both*, in python 3 the `<>` operator has been removed.

There is no difference between the two, but [`!=` is the preferred form](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons).

Answer (score 7):

From [the official docs you linked](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)

> != can also be written <>, but this is an obsolete usage kept for
>   backwards compatibility only. New code should always use !=.

I believe the rationale for originally accepting `<>` was that it looked more natural for someone coming from a mathematical background than the common C-style `!=` operator.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what documentation you read, but I'm not aware of any that recommends `<>` over `!=`. [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the main style guide, doesn't mention any such recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record,`<>` has been obsolete since at least as early as [version 1.4](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/ref/ref2.html#HDR20), which was released in October 1996.